# unwanted margin with css

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a fairly simple webpage and I'm a little bit dusty so I could've made a really obvious mistake but please stick with me. I'm getting a very thin (maybe 5-10px) margin on all sides of my document. I'm including an abbreviated version of my code. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting it and how to get rid of it.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="video">
</div>
<div id="para">
<p>Hello, I'm ...</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<ul id="social">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#wrap { background: url(Andres/images/background-bg.png);  margin: 0 auto;
 }

#para p { padding: 20px; }

#footer { background:url(Andres/images/footer.png); height: 80px;}

#footer #social li { float: left; padding: 10px; list-style: none; }
```

Comment: Are you inheriting some library that has a padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely the default margin on the `<body>` element - most browsers include 8px on all sides, just add:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Adrift's answer does answer your specific question - you might want to look at something like

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

It's provides a good baseline when starting a project in order to minimise css issues like the one you encountered

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to add a "reset" to your CSS to remove some of the cross browser quirks. I typically add at least this line to all of my projects:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Here's an [article](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) to check out about CSS resets.