# What specifically is the CSS reset changing here?

Tags: css, whitespace, margin

I am new to CSS and was trying to get rid of unwanted whitespace around my `body`. Following the advice of one of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892068/unwanted-margin-with-css) question, I included

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

in my CSS and the whitespace disappeared like I wanted it to. But when I first tried to insert just the following:

```
html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

only the whitespace on the left and right disappeared. The whitespace at the top remained. Why? What is the element that `*` removes a margin from and causes the top whitespace to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` selects all tags, I'm guessing it was a header causing the space at the top.

Comment: +1, you're probably right about `<h*>` element being the cause. )

Comment: So even though I didn't have a `<header>` element, one is created by default?

Comment: @user2433865 I was referring to the h1-h6 headers.

Answer (score 1):

Several HTML elements have a top margin by default. It could be an `h1` element (the most natural guess I would say), but it could also be `ul` for example. You really need to look at the HTML code to see what causes the spacing in the particular case.